# Seeking IBA shapefile for Denmark?

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for the shapes of important bird areas in Denmark, but cannot find it online. Have made a request to Bird Life, but have not heard from them yet.

So, anyone got a copy that they can share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important Bird Areas are part of The World Database of Key Biodiversity Areas. The [terms and conditions of use](http://www.keybiodiversityareas.org/info/dataterms) clearly state that redistribution is not allowed. See the relevant section quoted below:

> **4. No reposting and/or redistribution**
>
> Except as provided in this section 4, all forms of reposting, and any sub-licensing, reselling, or other forms of redistribution or communication to the public of the KBA Data in their original format, either whole or in part, alone or combined with other data, are strictly prohibited without the prior written permission of the KBA Secretariat. You may not repost, or redistribute to any third party, the KBA Data in whole, or in part, by any means, including (but not limited to) electronic formats such as internet postings, web downloads, through web services, through interactive web maps that grant users download access, KML files or through file transfer protocols, electronic mailing, faxing, archiving in a public data, redistributing via a computer network, digital storage, memory stick or other electronic media or device, except as may otherwise be expressly permitted by the KBA Secretariat in writing.
>
> If you wish to provide a service through which KBA Data are otherwise made available for reposting or otherwise made available for redistribution, you must obtain written permission by contacting the KBA Secretariat directly using the contact details below in section 16.
>
> You agree to direct all requests from third parties for access to the data you obtained from The KBA Website to the KBA Secretariat at the address stated in section 16.
>
> Notwithstanding this clause, and subject to the requirements of third-party content providers, donors and licensors, KBA Partners agree to grant BirdLife permission to license KBA Data for commercial use on their behalf via the Integrated Biodiversity Assessment Tool (IBAT), with the understanding that income thus generated will be allocated transparently in accordance with Art VI.H.m.